# Talend date conversion issue

Tags: talend

In talend, I am trying to load date from csv file in the format (mm/dd/year)1/14/2012(string format) to a database MySQL database. Whenever I am running the job I am getting an error default value is needed. I tried using talend parsing and staging option but still, I was facing this error. Please help me out.

Comment: Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information on how to ask a good question. Where is your code? We are not magicians.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a picture of your job layout, the error message and the "talend parsing".